# Can you fix the scrollbar on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div which has a height bigger than the screen and I want to leave this bit as is, but this div also has a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom and this one is not visible until the user scrolls all the way down, and this is a bit strage. You have to scroll down, scroll to the right and then scroll back up to see what you need. So I was wondering if there is a way to fix the bottom scrollbar at the bottom of the screen so that it's available at any time to the user.

Here are two prints to demonstrate my problem

What I have right now: http://imageshack.us/a/img132/2087/38417747.png

How I want to make it look: http://imageshack.us/a/img267/7452/90387247.png

I was going to design a scrollbar myself using jQuery but I want to know if this is doable without this much effort.

Example: Here you go: jsfiddle.net/jy3HK/

Also, please try to answer my question without modifying it. I want my application to be as customizable as possible. There is already an option to cancel the bottom scroll but I want to add this option too. Thank you.

Comment: please make test case on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: websites should be very easy to navigate why would you want a user to scroll both ways and finally they get control of what they looking at.How about putting a width on the div and a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: You should use either the scroll bars on the main window or the div. You should never have them both. Its not only painful for the dev but also in terms of user experience.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jy3HK/ Also, please try to answer my question without modifying it. I want my application to be as customizable as possible. There is already an option to cancel the bottom scroll but I want to add this option too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible, but require a tricky JS approach - there is no possible CSS solution to your question as far as I can reckon.

I have created a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/szuzk/, which is more or less a proof-of-concept modification to your original fiddle, but before you go off, I implore you to understand my approach first :)

The problem you have is that the scrollbar is at the bottom of the scrolling element, regardless of the height of the viewport. In order to bring the scrollbar to the bottom of the viewport (not the scrolling element), you will have to resize the element such that the bottom of the element is always at the bottom of the viewport, and not any lower.

This is done by detecting the `.scroll` event, and subsequently recalculating the element height on the go. However, this also means that the element will not take up the original 1500px height intended - so we create a wrap-around element and assign that height to it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Create wrap around element
    $('#big').wrap('<div id="scroll-wrap" />');

    // Function: resize element when scrolling
    function recalcHeight() {
         $('#big').css({
             'height': $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() - $('#big').offset().top
         });       
    }

    // Resize wrap around element upon resize
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#scroll-wrap').css({
            'height': $('#big').css('max-height')
        });
    }).resize(); // Fires resize() event onload

    // Recalculate height upon load, and upon scroll
    recalcHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        recalcHeight();
    });
});
```

That's all ;)

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful and I hate to return with a "but," but I have to. The scrolling effect is now very slow. I can imagine users that drag directly the scroll bar with their mouse will be mad because of this. Is there any other alternative to the .scroll event that is faster?

Comment: @user2301842 Would you mind defining what is "slow" - like, the browser lags when you scroll, or that the `<div>` element resizes slower than the speed of the scrolling?

Comment: The div element resizes slower than the speed of the scrolling. My app has no limit of content so I've teste this script on a <ul> containing over 2000 of <li> elements.

Comment: I don't think there's a way around that - I have similar lag when I use the scrollwheel, too.

Answer (score -1):

I Don't know why these developer always gives a large code while it has been handle with CSS like this:-

```
div.table-responsive {
   max-height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
}
table {
  height: 450px;
}
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```